# `No numeric types to aggregate` error with rolling sum and timedelta type

Tags: python, pandas, time, timedelta

I have the following column (timedelta Objects) which is the result of the difference between two time columns:

```
Duration
00:12:38.260000  
00:01:00.750000  
00:19:35.260000  
00:00:29.990000
```

I'm trying to apply the following on this column:

```
rolling(min_periods=3, window=5).sum()
```

I have the following error:

`No numeric types to aggregate`

Should I convert my duration? How?

Answer (score 0):

**short answer**

Convert to seconds with `.total_seconds()` then sum

**long answer**

Create your `dataframe` and `duration` column

```py
import pandas as pd

dt1 = ['2019-12-01 10:00:00', '2019-12-01 10:01:00', '2019-12-01 10:00:30', '2019-12-01 10:02:30', '2019-12-01 10:05:30']
dt2 = ['2019-12-01 10:10:00', '2019-12-01 11:06:00', '2019-12-01 10:01:00', '2019-12-01 10:02:30', '2019-12-01 10:07:30']

df = pd.DataFrame({'dt1': dt1, 'dt2': dt2})
df['dt1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dt1'])
df['dt2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dt2'])
df['duration'] = df['dt2'] - df['dt1']
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 3 columns):
dt1         5 non-null datetime64[ns]
dt2         5 non-null datetime64[ns]
duration    5 non-null timedelta64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](2), timedelta64[ns](1)
memory usage: 248.0 bytes
```

Note that duration is type `timedelta`.

Now convert to seconds with `.total_seconds()` then sum.

```
df['duration_rolling_sum'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['duration'].dt.total_seconds().rolling(min_periods=3, window=5).sum(), unit='s')

df

                  dt1                 dt2 duration duration_rolling_sum
0 2019-12-01 10:00:00 2019-12-01 10:10:00 00:10:00                  NaT
1 2019-12-01 10:01:00 2019-12-01 11:06:00 01:05:00                  NaT
2 2019-12-01 10:00:30 2019-12-01 10:01:00 00:00:30             01:15:30
3 2019-12-01 10:02:30 2019-12-01 10:02:30 00:00:00             01:15:30
4 2019-12-01 10:05:30 2019-12-01 10:07:30 00:02:00             01:17:30
```